# TextField Input, fonts are bigger when editing

Tags: iphone, flash, actionscript-3, textfield

When I test my Actionscript 3 flash program on my computer, there's nothing wrong. But when I transfer it to my iPhone and I click on the text I want to edit, I can edit it, but the characters grow bigger than they actually are while editing.

When I stop editing, the font gets back to the original size. How can I keep the font from growing when I edit it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was just having this problem. Use a classic text input textbox, set the font family, and for anti-alias choose "Use device fonts". This solves the zoom problem.